# Matlab heatmap/topological map

Tags: matlab

I have 3 vectors of data: latitudes, longitudes, and elevations of specific locations. Each vector (lat, lon, elev) is a column vector with about 63 elements where element 1 of each represents a given location. What I want to do is create a topological map, or heatmap (whichever you want to call it) to map out these locations. I can plot them (like lon vs lat) no problem, but I'm not sure where to look to create a topological map. I've looked at using the surf function, but the elevations need to be a 2-D matrix for that and that would result in a lot of missing data that I just don't have.

Can someone give me some guidance here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`TriScatteredInterp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triscatteredinterp.html) to interpolate your data onto a regular grid, which you then can use to plot the surface using `surf`, or a heatmap using `contourf`.

The example in the linked documentation of `TriScatteredInterp` will do exactly what you need, all you need to do is replace `x`, `y`, and `z` by your data and define the appropriate limits for `meshgrid`.

Comment: So I am a bit confused on the parameter **V** and what it is used for. If I understand the function correctly, this is what I would put: F=TriScatteredInterp(lon,lat,elev,V). Am I on the right track?

Comment: @rwb7041: `V` is `elev` in your example, so `F=TriScatteredInterp(lon,lat,elev)`